# JSON work with PHP like a array

Tags: php, json

I got the following code is there anyway to work with that like an array?

```
$var = 
"{"uid":"cb463625fc9dde2d82207e15bde1b674513094011b2976.06073807","name":"marius"}{"uid":"2393d7a6a3258894acc34581978453fa513094011b2ab8.28630478","name":"buenyamin"}";
```

to print it out like

```
echo $var[0].uid."<br>";
echo $var[1].uid;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
$array = json_decode($var,true);

echo "<pre>";    
print_r($array);
```

NOTE : the second parameter `true` in json_decode is needed to get the out put as array, else the output will be object

ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 1):

Use [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to decode a string into a PHP array.

```
$var = 
"{"uid":"cb463625fc9dde2d82207e15bde1b674513094011b2976.06073807","name":"marius"}{"uid":"2393d7a6a3258894acc34581978453fa513094011b2ab8.28630478","name":"buenyamin"}";
echo '<pre>' . print_r(json_code($var, true)) . '</pre>';
```